# В чём проблема в задании «Обработка пакетов через контейнер очередь»?

Tags: c++

Условие :
Первая строка входа содержит размер буфера `size` и
число пакетов `n`. Каждая из следующих `n` строк содержит два
числа: время `arrivali` прибытия i-го пакета и время `durationi`
, необходимое на его обработку. Гарантируется, что `arrival1 ≤ arrival2 ≤ · · · ≤ arrivaln`. При этом может оказаться, что
`arrivali−1 == arrivali`. В таком случае считаем, что пакет `i − 1` поступил раньше пакета `i`.
Формат вывода. Для каждого из `n` пакетов выведите время, когда
процессор начал его обрабатывать, или −1, если пакет был отброшен.
Ограничения. Все числа во входе целые.
`1 ≤ size ≤ 105;  0 ≤ n ≤ 105;
0 ≤ arrivali ≤ 106; 0 ≤ durationi ≤ 103;
arrivali ≤ arrivali+1 для всех 1 ≤ i ≤ n − 1.

Пример.
Вход:  1 0
Выход:  Если пакетов нет, выводить ничего не нужно.

Пример.
Вход:
1 1
0 0
Выход:
0
Пакет поступил в момент времени 0, и компьютер тут же начал его обрабатывать.

### Но при выводе у меня получается вход 1 0 и выход пустое значение (Empty result). В Visual studio проверял код - всё нормально, а вот в стёпике ругается. Может скажите как дополнить код чтоб решить данную ошибку?
вот остальные примеры :
Пример.
Вход:
1 1
0 0
Выход:
0
Пакет поступил в момент времени 0, и компьютер тут же начал
его обрабатывать.
12
Пример.
Вход:
1 2
0 1
0 1
Выход:
0

Первый пакет поступил в момент времени 0, второй пакет поступил также в момент времени 0, но был отброшен, поскольку буфер в этот момент полностью заполнен (первым пакетом).
Первый пакет начал обрабатываться в момент времени 0, второй был отброшен.
Пример.
Вход:
1 2
0 1
1 1
Выход:
0
1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int bufferSize, numPackets;
    
    queue<int> ends; // очередь окончаний
    int startTime = 0; // возможный старт

    for (int i = 0; i < numPackets; i++) {
        int arrival, duration;
        cin >> arrival >> duration;

        // выясняем, когда на самом деле можно стартовать пакет
        int realStart = max(startTime, arrival);

        // Извлекаем из очереди пакеты, которые обработаны на момент старта
        while (!ends.empty() && ends.front() <= realStart) {
            ends.pop();
        }

        if (ends.size() < bufferSize) {
            // если на момент старта есть места в очереди, стартуем
            cout << realStart << endl;
            startTime = realStart + duration; // окончание обработки
            ends.push(startTime);
        }
        else {
            // Очередь полна, пакет не может быть обработан
            cout << -1 << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как ругается?

Comment: как я понял он валиться на втором тесте из 22

Comment: Failed test #2 of 22. Wrong answer

This is a sample test from the problem statement!

Test input:
1 1
0 0

Correct output:
0

Your code output:

Comment: потом он валиться на Failed test #6 of 22. Wrong answer

Comment: Ну для входных данных  1 1 0 0 вроде правильно работает. Может числами нужно через пробел выводить, а не на отдельной строке? А для 6 теста какие входные данные?

Comment: в этом и проблема не могу понять какой 6 тест

Comment: тобишь на стёпике там какие то странные тесты

Answer (score 0):

Похоже у вас ошибка в вычислении текущего времени и обработке очереди.
По очереди - зачем от текущего времени отнимать размер буфера?

```
while (!packets.empty() && packets.front().first <= currentTime - bufferSize)
```

По вычислению времени - у вас должно быть 2 отметки время прихода очередного пакета и время, когда процессор сможет взять очередной пакет на обработку. А

```
currentTime = arrival + duration;
```

верно только для первого пришедшего пакета.
Смысл в том, что очередь наполняется асинхронно, т.е. процессор не знает сколько там элементов - он берет очередной из очереди. И тогда допустим первый пакет 0 5, второй пакет 3 5. Процессор второй пакет начнет обрабатывать только после того, как обработает 1 пакет. Т.е. начало обработки второго пакета будет 5, а конец - 10, несмотря на то, что он пришел на отметке 3. Возможно за это время придет ещё 2 пакета, например 5 5 и 7 5, но они начнут обрабатываться только на отметках 10 и 15.
Тут должен быть немного другой алгоритм - сначала запишите все пакеты в очередь (массив),  а потом идете по очереди, высчитываете время и проверяете мог пакет попасть в очередь или нет.
Ещё вариант - текущее время считать отдельно, на каждой итерации инкрементируя - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... И сравнивать время прибытия пакета и время окончания операции с текущим. Но тогда будут пустые итерации.
Или как у вас, но на каждой итерации текущее время нужно вычислять вначале и оно должно быть равно минимуму из времени прихода пакета и времени окончания обработки предыдущего пакета.

```
int i = 0;
int currentTime = 0;
int arrival, duration;
cin >> arrival >> duration;
int timeToEnd = arrival + duration; // взяли на обработку 1 пакет
cout << arrival << " ";
while(i < numPackets or !packets.empty() )
{
   currentTime = min(arrival, timeToEnd);
   if(currentTime == arrival)
       // проверить можно ли добавить пакет в очередь и считать следующий пакет
   if(currentTime == timeToEnd)
       // значит завершилась обработка предыдущего пакета 
       // можно взять из очереди следующий пакет на обработку
}
```

Только нужно определиться с последовательностью - кто выполняет операцию вперед при одинаковом времени. Сначала процессор заберет пакет из очереди, или сначала новый пакет попытается стать в очередь. От этого зависит результат.

Comment: спасибо за помощь подумаю как это сделать просто я еле с одной отметкой разобрался а тут их надо две плюс ещё переделать алгоритм я так понимаю проще по новой всё писать

Comment: вот чутка поправил скажите что может ещё поменять чтоб заработало

Comment: А пакеты всё равно надо сначала все считывать. У вас по условию - вывести для каждого пакета время, когда процессор начал его обрабатывать, или −1, если пакет был отброшен. Т.е. все пакеты считать, и только потом проверять был он отброшен или нет.